# Redirect using .htaccess from http to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have two domains on the same server. One domain is for production and the other is for testing content before it is copied over to the production.  I am trying to create a rewrite rule that redirects http to https.  How can I write it so that domain name is not hard coded?  The reason I need this is when I copy the tested content to the production server I don't want have to change the .htaccess file.  Here is what I have but it doesn't work.

```
 # Prevent SSL cert warnings
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close in your attempt.

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: For clarification, are you filling in the SERVER_NAME or leaving it as written?

Comment: Didn't understand your question. As you can see I am not using `SERVER_NAME` in my answer just using `HTTP_HOST`

Comment: Sorry, are you filling in the HTTP_HOST then or leaving it as written?

Comment: Question is about `http -> https` so `HTTP_HOST` is carried over to https URL

Comment: Ok, so you don't need to replace HTTP_HOST with www.example.com?

Comment: no I have already explained why. It is carried over from original request

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on


RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```